# Click trough overlay element

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="top">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.bottom{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I got 2 blocks, top and bottom.  In bottom block there is an image that should overlay top block in one place. it overlays Ok but I can't click on element from top block cause browser think i click on bottom. How can it be resolved?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
pointer-events : none;
```

to your `.bottom` element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Thank you, this is what I exactly needed